# Игнорирование max_execution_time

Tags: php, apache

Приветствую.
Никак не могу разобраться с временем выполнения скриптов. Устал уже гуглить. На сервере макс. выполнение - 60 секунд. 
В php.ini (Loaded Configuration File - /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini) сменил max_execution_time на 0, перезапустил, phpinfo() также показывает 0, но все равно выполняется только 60 секунд. В чем может быть дело? Есть еще какие-то конфиги?
Спасибо.

Comment: возможно, более правильным было бы начать с другой стороны вопроса: а стоит ли вообще запускать такие «долгоиграющие» скрипты через http-сервер? картина: пользователь нажимает ссылку … и ждёт целую минуту появления страницы.

Comment: если всё-таки «очень надо», то вопрос: как вы определяте, что скрипт прекращает выполняться?

Comment: Это max_input_time 60 секунд или что-то типа этого. Процессы то висят наверное. Сервер ещё может рубить, см. TimeOut у Apache к примеру...

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, скрипт курлом обращается к урлам сайтов и заголовки читает. я его сам запускать собираюсь раз в несколько дней.

Comment: @Deadooshka, это я тоже в 0 выставил, не помогло.

Comment: @DaHuJIka, я просто обратил ваше внимание на, как мне представляется, «архитектурную ошибку». ведь описанные действия очень похожи на «типичное поведение сервиса». логично сделать так, чтобы пользователь лишь командовал сервисом (определял, когда его следует запустить, просматривал отчёт о работе и т.п.)

Comment: Если у вас что-то выполняется шестьдесят секунд, то это не должно выполняться в контексте запроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно учить матчасть. Проблема была в nginx, а не в apache. Я по началу и не обратил внимания на ошибку 504, заострил лишь внимание на том, что получаю ее ровно спустя 60 секунд. 
Решил просто - выставил бОльшие таймауты в /etc/nginx/nginx.conf, т.е. добавил proxy_send_timeout 3000 и proxy_read_timeout 3000 в секцию http.
Всем спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

в PHP В начале кода set_time_limit($seconds); 
или ini_set('max_execution_time', $seconds); 
или в php.ini

есть еще вариант в .htaccess php_value max_execution_time 60

Comment: Насколько я могу понять, если в php.ini выставлено max_execution_time = 0, то подобные конструкции уже бесполезны, они ведь нужны, чтоб переопределить проставленное значение. Если ошибаюсь, то поправьте, нужно убивать безграмотность :)

Comment: если PHP запущен в безопасном режиме, То нельзя, а так пожалуйста, кто вам мешает