# max_execution_time + xdebug

Tags: php, apache, время, xdebug, execute

В /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini указано max_execution_time = 30
Но поведение сервера не соответствует этому значению. Это может быть из-за того что совместно используется xdebug?
Если это из-за xdebug - то этому есть вполне логическое объяснение. А если не из-за него...(?)

Время выполнения не ограничено.

Я уже забыл как ставил xdebug. Хочу попробовать отключить\удалить его и без него проверить действует ли ограничение на время выполнения скриптов.

[Игнорирование max_execution_time](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/430486/%D0%98%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-max-execution-time) это не мой случай.

Answer (score 1):

Удалить xdebug:

`sudo apt-get remove php5-xdebug`

Comment: Я ПОЛНОСТЬЮ удалял xdebug и apache2 !!! Потом снова установил апач. Специально видео сделал. Это не трюк - это глюк.  Щас видео загружу...

Comment: ПЕРЕСНЯЛ ВИДЕО https://youtu.be/g_mEvsu9qDE

загадка за загадкой. то sql глючит... тепер вот это вот. :( 

Некритично, но ПОЧЕМУ??

Comment: Методом научного тыка выяснл, что при помощи ini_set можно управлять временем выполнения. И в итоге (при превышении допустимого времени) будет долгожданная ошибка.

    Fatal error: Maximum execution time of XX second exceeded in /var/www/html/why.php on line 11

По прежнему я без понтятия почему это в php.ini игнорируется.

Comment: Если у вас php в режиме fpm, то максимальное выполнение скрипта задается в файле php-fpm.conf или www.conf(точно не помню), хотя у вас апач...

Comment: Я менял значение в php.ini. В выводе phpinfo() оно изменялось  (на то что я устанавливал), НО все равно скрипты выполнялись бы вечность. Но у меня php "приклеен" к апачу в виде модуля.
Нашел пару интересных мест 

/etc/alternatives/php

/etc/alternatives/php-config
 нужно посмотреть что там интересного.